# How can I use Swift 2.3 in XCode 8 Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcode8

I have my playground project written in Swift 2.2 and I want take advantage of timeline visuals and try new debug features introduced in Xcode 8 beta. By default, Xcode 8 beta is using Swift 3 in Playgrounds and I cannot find a way to change that. Updating my code to Swift 3 is not an option unfortunately, because my code will be compiled on server with Swift 2.2 environment.

Comment: when you say playground project, do you mean a `.playground` or a `.xcodeproj`?

Comment: I mean `.playground`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to Apple it is impossible:

> For instance, Playgrounds in Xcode only work with Swift 3, and notably the Swift Playgrounds app for iPad also uses Swift 3. Xcode project templates all use Swift 3, and all documentation is presented in a format appropriate for Swift 3.

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36).

Answer (score -2):

You can convert your Swift 2.2 to Swift 2.3 for use in Xcode-beta 8.

Yes, Swift 3 is the default, but you get the following dialog when you do `Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax...` in Xcode.

This also created an entry in my project.pbxproj for `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3`

[image]

Comment: Does not answer the question of how to change the swift version playgrounds is using.

Comment: @RobLabs It doesn't work for me. 
If I save Playground as workspace, `Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax...` becomes available but it hangs with message `"Generating preview..."`.

Comment: I think It is a different case because Playgrounds doesn't contain *.pbxproj package and therefore there is no project settings so `SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3` cannot be set.

Comment: This definitely does not work, after trying a number of different things there is no way to tell a Playground to use anything but the most recent version of Swift in Xcode.

Answer (score -4):

I have a legacy playground (created using xcode 7) in a project that I've migrated to Swift 2.3 syntax on XCode 8 and my playground work even if it's still using Swift 2.3 syntax, so I guess there is a way.